What is the purpose of the philosophy of science?
I'll start by saying I'm on the spectrum, so philosophy already gives me a hard time every time I try to read it. I understand what the terms mean and what the schools are about but not what they "mean" as in the major point or how they all come together.
That said I love reading about science and nature and technology and learning all about the world around me. But when I get to the philosophy of science a lot of my attempts at it all are trying to figure out the "so what", as in what does it mean in simple terms.
Does it mean that science isn't true or reliable? Is it saying there is no external world or other people because there is no universal standard we have to measure it all by? Is it saying there is no point reading any science or tech book to learn about stuff because we have no standard so it's all wrong?
If you can't tell I get VERY confused by all this and my brain wracks itself trying to get it and what to do about it. What is the point of it exactly and what does it all mean? I'm sorry that it's vague but I don't know how else to put it.
Does it mean I can't do science or learn about the world? That would mean me having to give up something I enjoy very much because all the info would be wrong...
So, what, then, is the purpose of the philosophy of science?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Modern empirical science as you are familiar with it today is a philosophy and it was originally developed by philosophers.  It didn't exist prior to around the 17th century and was developed by key figures like Francis Bacon, who collectively developed the methodology of the scientific method as a systematic method of observation and experimentation we know of today.
"Does it mean that science isn't true or reliable?"
"Is it saying there is no external world or other people because there is no universal standard we have to measure it all by?"
These would be more basic epistemological questions.  Epistemology is the philosophical study of knowledge, of which scientific inquiry is a subset.  The philosophy of science is mainly concerned with the foundations methods and implications of scientific inquiry.  When you get into basic epistemology you are asking broader questions that apply to all knowledge.
"Is it saying there is no point reading any science or tech book to learn about stuff because we have no standard so it's all wrong?"
No, science is one of humanity's clearly useful methodological ways of learning about the world with practical, real world benefits that are obvious to all.
"Does it mean I can't do science or learn about the world? That would mean me having to give up something I enjoy very much because all the info would be wrong..."
No.  You should question any philosopher who suggests that.

Philosophy is a weak point of mine so whenever I read stuff like this I start to think that means that nothing is real since there is no objective standard.
Like...on some level I understand that science is clearly useful and we do have knowledge of the world and things in it. I can see that with my own eyes but trying to accept that is difficult. Mostly because I don't really understand what folks in philosophy of science say or mean.

Well the philosophers who developed science were trying to find a way to have more objectivity in how we study the world.  In practical terms it's hard to say that they failed completely.  A philosopher can argue that this doesn't give us absolute objectivity but you can judge for yourself how much we ought to pay attention to such a criticism.  There are plenty of philosophers of science who are merely trying to make science better rather than make nihilistic criticisms though.  Generally the purpose of the philosophy of science is to improve science.

The more I read it the more confused I get: anti-realism, quantifier variance, two dogmas of empiricism, reification fallacy, natural kinds, death of the analytic-synthetic divide? What the hell are people talking about? I don't get any of it.

suggest: "humanities" -> "humanity's"

The purpose of the philosophy of science is to explain where the ideas in science come from, why it works and why we should trust it, roughly speaking.
If you're reading things that seem concerning, but you don't quite understand it, it's probably worth noting that, for every philosophical argument, there is probably some argument for an opposing point. For every philosophical problem, there are probably some attempts to resolve it. And there is also a whole lot of word salad in philosophy, that isn't worth the paper it's printed on (in my opinion, at least). Had my philosophy journey started by opening the wrong book, I'd probably have gone running for the hills. But there are certainly more approachable parts, and those also provide a path and give you the tools to deconstruct those things that didn't make any sense to you to begin with (and when you break those things down into understandable parts, you may realise that there isn't actually much substance behind many of those things).
My general philosophy (... on philosophy, and on other things) is that one should be able to explain one's argument in a way practically anyone can understand, and a failure to do so says more about the speaker than the listener (although not everything is intended for every audience).
My advice: don't panic. I would strongly recommend that everyone gets some basic understanding of epistemology and moral philosophy (to judge what's reasonable to believe and what's right and wrong, and why that's so). But if you don't want to do philosophy, then don't do philosophy. Science is one of the most reliable tools we have for gaining knowledge. You might read a few thousand pages of philosophy to understand what science truly tells us, what knowledge is and what we can fundamentally know. But I'd say it's also fine to just stick to "science is reliable".
Can science be wrong?
There is one important way science can be "wrong" (in practice), but this isn't quite as much of a problem as some people try to paint it as.
I might explain this with an example.
Imagine there's a ball rolling down a smooth hill. Now we might use some nice and simple formulas to calculate the path of the ball using the incline of the hill, friction, acceleration, etc. We could be exceedingly effective at predicting the path of the ball.
But now we might zoom in, and we might see loads of little bumps in the hill, and we might see the ball moving up and down by just a tiny bit, and it may move a tiny bit slower here and a tiny bit faster there. This tells us that our formulas above are technically "wrong", because the hill isn't technically perfectly smooth, and the ball technically isn't moving along a straight line with constant acceleration. Yet our predictions were still exceedingly accurate, and we may continue to use that "wrong" model because it's much simpler than trying to account for every little bump.
Now imagine you're seeing the ball and the hill on a screen. You have no idea where in the world the ball is, if it's a live recording, or if it's computer-generated. Yet you can still accurately predict the path of the ball all the same.
We might also imagine that we notice after 1000 km, that we're off by a few millimeters. So we go back to our formulas, and maybe we see that we'd get more accurate predictions if we increase the value of friction in the formula by just a little bit, or maybe we were including air resistance within friction, but it would be more accurate to split that into separate values. That doesn't mean all our past correct predictions are now actually wrong: those were still correct, and they should be near-identical with the new model, but other predictions would now be more accurate.
That is what science is and does. It just models the behaviour of things at different scales (which it's really good at), and it lets philosophers worry about the fundamental nature of what those things are (although it doesn't seem like we can know what the "fundamental nature" of things are, if that's even a coherent concept - it doesn't seem worth worrying about).

I am an amateur philosopher, but maybe that helps me see your question from your perspective. Your post mentioned that you understand the term "philosophy," but let me start there anyway since I'll build on that.
Aristotle was a Greek philosopher who wrote a number of treatises. One was on the nature of the physical world and was called "Physics."  In a later anthology of Aristotle's works, the treatise sequenced after "Physics" was on the nature of reality itself, and was named "Metaphysics" since "meta," in Greek, simply means "after."  However, over the years, "meta" acquired a new meaning of "at a higher level of abstraction" (at least in English). Which is why we have the term "metadata," which is "data about data";
i.e., cataloging and indexing information about books or other sources of information. If I give a lecture, you can give a lecture describing my lecture: a "meta-lecture."
So the philosophy of science is meta-science. Science tries to understand the natural world. Philosophy of science tries to understand science itself.
Or another analogy: philosophy is to science as science is to engineering...
philosophy:science::science:engineering

...in both analogies, the first term is about asking questions and proposing answers (or maybe proposing methods for finding answers), while the second term is about applying those methods. Philosophy of science is about how and why to conduct science.
Maybe that will help with the question about the "purpose" of philosophy of science.  If that answer seems broad, it should. Philosophy can get very broad with indistinct boundaries. (For example, the field of Evidence Based Medicine, that seeks to evaluate the reliability of different forms of medical research, is probably part philosophy and part science.)
As for the "meaning" of philosophy of science...

Does it mean that science isn't true or reliable? Is it saying there
is no external world or other people because there is no universal
standard we have to measure it all by? Is it saying there is no point
reading any science or tech book to learn about stuff because we have
no standard so it's all wrong?

...Those are the kinds of questions philosophers ask. If they confuse you, join the club. I can only suggest:

Be pragmatic. Even if you are nothing but a brain in a vat, and everything you see, hear, touch, taste, and feel is "fake," due to electronic signals being fed to your brain, that's still what you need to deal with on a day to day basis. You will get hungry and need to eat. If the meal you eat is ultimately just fake electric signals, what of it? It tastes good and satisfies your hunger.
Learn to live with uncertainty. We may never know what happened to Amelia Earhart or Jimmy Hoffa; if there is intelligent life elsewhere in the universe; or where the ultimate principles came from that later allowed the universe to come into being. That's to be expected.  Children love to ask their parents a series of "why" questions, drilling down further and further. Sooner or later the only truthful answer is "that's just the way it is" or "No one knows."


Last para is key. We must live with uncertainty. The only options are: Do it cheerfully; Or do it kicking and screaming

Well Rushi isn't right about the uncertainty. The stuff you mentioned about Amelia, Jimmy, intelligent life, or how the universe came to be don't really matter to me. I'm fine with that uncertainty, I know I won't learn everything. But that isn't the uncertainty I'm talking about in my question.

@BoltStorm: Those examples were just that: mere examples that there will always be some uncertainties in life. I didn't meant to imply that those particular issues were ones that kept you up at night. But I did re-read your post to try to better understand what kind of uncertainty you are referring to.  On another read, this part stood out: "no point reading any science or tech book to learn about stuff because we have no standard so it's all wrong?" Have you read Isaac Asimov's The Relativity of Wrong?  https://hermiene.net/essays-trans/relativity_of_wrong.html

@SyntaxJunkie So...it's just about being less wrong? I heard that quote from him about the flat earth and the sphere earth. I did like his response to the Socrates line because IMO that always smacked of just being lazy and clinging to mysticism, I say that because pretty much every New Agey or spiritual type flings that line at me when I don't buy what they're selling. But I don't think that really answered my question, is that a yes or no on it being pointless?

@BoltStorm. "it's just about being less wrong?...is that a yes or no on it it being pointless?" It depends on your goal. If your goal is to design a bridge, then classical physics is enough. If you want the next generation particle collider, then you need to enough relativity and QM to meet design specs. But you don't need to know everything about everything. Asimov's article is an example of what "Philosophy of Science" is about. "Does it mean that science isn't true or reliable?" It's reliable enough for us to be having this electronic exchange, right? It goes back to being pragmatic.

@SyntaxJunkie That's not really answering my question, it's just a yes or no for me. The point in my original post is that if there is no universal standard then does that mean reading and learning about it is pointless or not. I read what Asimov said but it's not really getting at what I mean.

@SyntaxJunkie if science deals in expediency  — we're having this electronic exchange, so science is wonderful — then fine. The difficulty arises when the second claim mysteriously pops up — science deals in truth. And then ultimate truth. Here's a bunch of testing questions to check the limits

@BoltStorm: "it's just a yes or no for me..." It seems you might have a preference for black-and-white thinking. I don't think I have much else to offer that fits a yes-or-no paradigm.

@Rushi Well it’s not really an issue. Science does deal in truth, that’s why it refines in light of new evidence. As for ultimate truth, I don’t think science ever claims that, that’s religion. But those testing questions I saw don’t seem to test much. Also looking at your answers not getting votes sorta tells me you’re not worth reading. I’m also basing that on the replies you gave here.

@SyntaxJunkie Your answer seems to suggest “yes”, that it’s worth reading about science even if you don’t directly say so. But I’m often wary when people say they can’t put it into a yes or no answer. My philosophy the teacher could, at least the one class I took. He mentioned that’s sorta key to philosophy, using such questions to get at what people believe. If folks avoid them then they’re hiding something. Either way I did appreciate the essay by Asimov, kinda helped me a bit.

@BoltStorm. I've left a second answer after reading and trying to understand your comments. The "thrust" of the answer was too far afield of this one to try to include it as an edit.


Philosophy is a weak point of mine so whenever I read stuff like this I start to think that means that nothing is real since there is no objective standard.
From here

Hmm... Nihilism...
In a saner past-er world one could say: Beware of nihilism — it is the whiff of the devil. But today we may not...
Let's move ahead

Philosophy has a habit of mucking my brain up, not triggering thoughts or facilitating the process. I end up stuck on the same point for months.
From here

In that case drop it!!. When you want to see something that someone else points to: you need to turn your head in the right direction, try to look with reasonable attention and focus, but not try too hard!
Let's say I say: Oooo! See that beautiful red and purple bird in the tree out there!

You turn to where (you think) I'm pointing
You try to look
You see nothing

Now what??
There are two choices:

You can literalistically, legalistically obey, not swerving ever so slightly from where (you imagine) I'm pointing, stare fixedly till your eyes burn. Finally give up crying in frustration.
You can try to disobey ever so slightly — something like when a drawer is stuck coming out you knock it in to free it to come out. Likewise here: You look a little here and there not exactly where (you think) I'm pointing, you relax your eyes, defocus them, close them. Then try again.

Which approach do you think will show you the bird faster??
So...
If philosophy of science fries your brain, don't go there (for a while).
There are many many areas of philosophy other than philosophy if science

P. of language
P. of religion
P. of technology
P. of morality/ethics
Etc

Here's a decent list of philosophy questions. Try knocking the hamner of science on these.
von Neuman was once asked by a student: I dont understand math at all.
von Neumann responded: My boy you dont understand math; you just get used to it.
Likewise here. Get used to the modus operandi of philosophy on areas that dont knock you out before you tackle those harder (for you).

Well...I can't just drop it, my brain doesn't work that way. Also philosophy for me wasn't a come back to it later and you'll get it, I'm still stuck on past thinkers and it's been 10 years. Like I said, autism...

@BoltStorm Well that's our difficulty universally. Everyone is stuck with some thoughts that are known to be unhelpful on quieter maturer reflection. But we cannot let go. All the meditation practices are for thus only. It's clear that Phil. Of science is a subject that derails you. I have a conjecture why but you do not give enough leads to confirm the conjecture.  Viz. You think science is already at the issue of truth. So you don't see the space or relevance of philosophy.  Think of an excited child in a movie theatre. Wildly enamored of the movie, unable to see/remember

I told you why already. I'm on the spectrum, meaning this sorta stuff doesn't go well for me.

Two of my favorite quotes are:

I’ve yet to see any problem, however complicated, which when you
looked at it the right way didn’t become still more complicated.
– Poul Anderson


It ain’t what you don’t know that gets you into trouble. It’s what you
know for sure that just ain’t so.
-Sometimes attributed to Mark Twain

These quotes are aphorisms, not absolute truths. Of course you will find exceptions. They are meant to be humorous, possibly at the expense of accuracy. The kernel of truth they are getting at is that:

Sometimes situations are more complicated than they appear
Misconceptions can often get in the way of learning

I am tempted to list examples, but for the sake of keeping this post concise, I will trust that both kinds of circumstances are common enough to almost everyone that they will have plenty of their own, first-hand examples.
I think they also explain a lot of philosophical writing. Philosophy (of science or otherwise) isn't exclusively about them. But a lot of philosophical writing is. As a trite example (I am not a learned philosopher), in The Structure of Scientific Revolutions, Thomas Kuhn argues that science is not the slow, steady progress of ever improving approximations that it is often assumed to be.  Instead, he sees it more as a matter of "punctuated equilibrium" (a metaphor I am making from evolutionary biology).
So if you're finding it hard to sink your teeth into the Philosophy of Science, or finding it disorienting because it offers no "universal standard," that's because that's not what Philosophy of Science is (always) meant to do. It's not necessarily intended to provide answers. Sometimes the purpose is to challenge some of our assumptions.

Well I can't really understand what it's saying or what it means, let alone what philosophy in general is saying. Every time I try to read the entries on the Stanford or otherwise I just get lost and my brain is fried. But because I don't get it my brain makes stuff up about what I think people are saying.

+1 "It's not necessarily intended to provide answers. Sometimes the purpose is to challenge some of our assumptions." I think sometimes this is why working scientists roll their eyes, and yet history of science is replete with bad ideas!


Does it mean that science isn't true or reliable? Is it saying there is no external world or other people because there is no universal standard we have to measure it all by? Is it saying there is no point reading any science or tech book to learn about stuff because we have no standard so it's all wrong?

Empirical science is not about trying to acquire absolutely certain knowledge or irrefutable theories. It's about starting from very ordinary, everyday questions, and trying to find answers and explanations, by gathering more data, more evidence, and improving, refuting or creating theories. The essence of science is not knowledge, but research, inquiry.
Once you actually engage in research, you'll find there are always conflicting theories, since there are always still open questions, and sometimes we may not (yet) have the data or the tools to determine which theory is more likely to be correct.
The totally general questions that are sometimes brought up in philosophy, such as whether any theory is true, or whether "there is" an "external" world or whether there are "other minds" -- those questions are mostly irrelevant and uninteresting for scientists. They do not gives us better tools and don't help us decide which scientific theories are better than others.
But philosophy can also be made more concrete -- starting from common, unproblematic observations. We talk about "science". There are different sciences, different departments in academia and in the corporate world where people "do science". So, we can adopt the point of view of a 12-year old, and ask: What is that? What are they doing? What is it that characterizes "science"? We can also ask: Why are they doing whatever it is they are doing? Why do we (as society, as corporation, as individual) spend money on it? Why do we spend time and money on the things that we're actually researching rather than on other things -- either other research topics or totally other endeavors like stimulating and supporting artists? -- We can ask several other, related questions (Who is doing what? Why are there more men then women in some field? Could that somehow influence the results? etc. etc.)
All those questions are entry points in a "philosophy of science". Some of them may be more factual, historical questions. But when you dive into them, you'll quickly find them entangled with normative questions and beliefs. And despite the philosophical dogma that "an is cannot be derived from an ought", it may be impossible to unravel the way basic facts and norms are knitted together. (An experiment is done to generate some data. The reliability of the data depends -- among other things -- on how careful the experiment was set up. Learning to research something, a teacher should teach us to be careful, should teach good methods. Learning something for ourselves is impossible if we're not self-critical; whatever we find needs to be reproducible; we need to be able to show others how they can come to the same findings. When we talk about "science", by default we mean "good science", "science as it should be practiced".)

There is an old philosophical conundrum about color perception:

We both look at a plant and agree that its leaves are green. But how do we know we're really seeing the same color?

When people first read or hear a question like this, they may be extremely puzzled and think: "Yes, I don't have her experience, I cannot see her perception, so how could I ever know?" It's indeed disturbing to consider that we couldn't ever know. (And if this is so for colors, then how about any other perceptions?)
One of the first philosophers to bring up essentially the same issue was Zhuangzi. He tells an amusing dialog between himself and his friend Hui Shi.
莊子與惠子遊於濠梁之上。莊子曰：「儵魚出遊從容，是魚樂也。」惠子曰：「子非魚，安知魚之樂？」莊子曰：「子非我，安知我不知魚之樂？」惠子曰：「我非子，固不知子矣；子固非魚也，子之不知魚之樂全矣。」莊子曰：「請循其本。子曰『汝安知魚樂』云者，既已知吾知之而問我，我知之濠上也。」

Zhuangzi and Huizi were taking a carefree walk along the dam over the Hao. Zhuangi said: "The minnows are darting about so spontaneously and carefree, that's the joy of fishes!" Huizi said: "You are not a fish. How would you know the joy of fishes?" Zhuangzi replied: "You are not me. How would you know I don't know the joy of fishes?" Huizi said: "Ha! I am not you, so indeed I don't know about you. But you are not a fish, so, by the same token, [the proof] that you don't know the joy of fishes is complete!" Zhuangzi said: "Let's go back to where we started from. You asked me 'How [from where] do you know fishes' joy'. So, in saying that, you already knew I knew, when you asked me. I knew it from [standing] above the river Hao.

There is a lot going on in this short passage, but I'll only highlight what I think is the core. (Well, one core. If you hold it up differently, you'd see other facets coming to the foreground.) Zhuangzi is here flirting with a representational theory of meaning, but suggests that this leads to solipsism, and that solipsism is essentially inconsistent. The very last statement suggests that an externalist theory of meaning may be a better approach. (For more on externalist theories of meaning, see for instance the books by Herman Cappelen and Josh Dever. For externalism in Chinese philosophy, see for instance the excellent study about Mozi by Chris Fraser - who is also the author of the SEP entry about Mohism. In that entry look for "standard(s)". Fraser's background knowledge about contemporary analytic philosophy seems a bit limited, but is much better than that of earlier sinologists.)
To come back to the color conundrum. There is some merit to this. The phenomenon of color blindness was only discovered very late; for millennia no one suspected that something like this existed. But the way color blindness was discovered, I think, also shows the (externalist) way out of the puzzle. Color blindness was first discovered around 1794, more or less by accident, starting with a vague feeling of wonder ("something is not quite right in our way of speaking -- why do we use these color words this way?"), by an eminent naturalist who himself  suffered from color blindness (without at first being aware of it), the chemist John Dalton. His account of Extraordinary facts relating to the vision of colours is an exemplary, careful, naturalistic account of how science discovers new phenomena. The account itself anchors the word "color blindness".

+1 "Empirical science is not about trying to acquire absolutely certain knowledge or irrefutable theories." The OP should read the IEP's article Fallibilism for an affirmation of this claim. Science is a process that construct knowledge, not a dogmatic set of truths!

Well...the color conundrum doesn't really bother me. Especially since we are starting to find that the brain is the result of all these things, but even if we didn't that doesn't bother me. I trust them when they say that or believe we are seeing green. Our views of reality aren't so different where I see a car and someone sees a tree, then I'd have questions. That view of science is that one I heard, where it's just our best guess based on the data and it could be wrong. But given what it's given us it's a safe bet to me.

@JD From what I sorta know science does have a dogmatic set of truths same as any knowledge, there are some things you just have to accept as truth. Part of that is an external world and other people, otherwise science would be pointless. Without other people you cannot verify the results independently, meaning you'll just have one data to work with. As for an external world, well we have to be testing something. Though besides that it doesn't have dogma. All I really care is whether there is an external world and other people, everything else has secondary importance.

Richard Feynman famously said that philosophy of science is about as useful to scientists as ornithology is to birds... To which one could object that ornithology is not meant to be useful to birds, but rather it's meant to be useful to men trying to understand birds. Likewise, philosophy of science is not primarily meant for scientists, but for non-scientists trying to understand science, how it works in practice, and how it can be useful to society (or harmful, e.g. in the case of fake/bad science).
There is value in that because society pays for science, with money that may potentially be better used elsewhere, and also because societies must heed the warnings of scientists e.g. on COVID or climate change. So it's important that politicians and the general public have a general understanding of how scientists work and what they can and cannot deliver, Feynman be damned.
Of particular importance here is the idea that science is 'happily fallible', that it's never about absolute certainty, but about getting it wrong and trying again until you get it about right. If you take science as a source of certainty, you're getting it wrong, and if any scientist tells you that he cannot be wrong, ever, then he is a liar.
You (OP) seem to enjoy scientific vulgarisation as a source of wonder, as an intellectual pleasure. There's of course nothing wrong with that. My wife is like that: she delights in listening to podcasts about botany and zoology, topics on which I happen to have some academic training. So, when she bursts into the room and asks, all excited: "did you know that squids can count?", for a while I would reply something like: "we have good reasons to believe that squids can compare small numbers accurately for hunting purposes, but there's more to "counting" than being able to tell that 7 is larger than 5." And then she would get all angry at me and my endless finessing.
Nowadays I just respond something like: "oh woah!" She wants to marvel, and my nuances are ruining it for her, so why mention them?
Yet, the way I see it, nuance and doubt are inherent to science, and science is more beautiful that way, not less. I consider knowledge to be marvelous, just like my wife does, but I also marvel at the knowledge about the limits of our knowledge.
Science is not a dogma. It must not be idolized. It's not a job that just gets done and then it's over. Rather it's a never-ending quest, something of a sysiphian task. And there's something noble and beautiful in that.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You ask:

What is the purpose of the philosophy of science?

The purpose of any philosophy-of is to explain the object of inquiry. That is to say, the purpose of the philosophy of logic is to explain what logic is and is not and how it works. The purpose of the philosophy of psychology is to explain what psychologists do and don't do and often what they should do. Thus, the philosophy of science is to explain what the term 'science' encompasses and what various scientists do. Strictly speaking, scientists do not (consciously at least) use philosophy of science on a day to day basis. Additionally, one should accept there are many uses of the term 'science', and they do not all agree or overlap.
Karl Popper most famously called this philosophical discussion on what it means to have or do 'science' the demarcation problem. The term 'science' might be used by an astrologer, but an astronomer would reject astrology as a science. Today, after several hundred years since natural philosophy has grown into modern and then post-modern science, what it means to be a science has changed. Galileo added mathematics to the discipline of science, George Boole suggested that there were Laws of Thought, and Albert Einstein used math and logic to show that Newtonian science was inadequate for understanding space travel and using GPS.
Philosophy of science, then, is a community of thinkers across time and space that focuses on these historical events, and philosophical questions which might be called the Metaphysics of Science (IEP). From the IEP:

Metaphysics of Science is the philosophical study of key concepts that figure prominently in science and that, prima facie, stand in need of clarification. It is also concerned with the phenomena that correspond to these concepts. Exemplary topics within Metaphysics of Science include laws of nature, causation, dispositions, natural kinds, possibility and necessity, explanation, reduction, emergence, grounding, and space and time.

That is to say, there are often presumptions about science that can be exposed as false or supported as truths. One famous group of philosophers of science were the logical empiricists and positivists and they exposed some presumptions about philosophy. Men like Carnap, Ayer, and Hempel tried to show that we can describe the universe objectively, and that philosophy itself really was just an exercise in defining vocabulary. Those claims were shown by Quine, Sellars, Kuhn, and others to be bad presumptions.
Philosophers of science also show how there is no one "science"; rather there are many different types of sciences: formal sciences (logic and mathematics), the general sciences (physics and psychology), the special sciences (medical sciences and earth sciences), the natural sciences (physics, chemistry, and biology) and the social sciences (sociology, economics, and religious studies) are a few. They each have different theoretical frameworks and methodologies. They also try to decide what are pseudosciences.
Philosophers of science also debate various aspects of what makes science successful and what goes on methodologically, psychologically, and sociologically. Is science primarily about making sense of empirical observations (David Hume)? Is it the rhetoric of science (Alan Gross)? Is it a series of political struggles within an institution (Thomas Kuhn)? Is it the ability to falsify claims (Karl Popper)? Is about applying deductive reasoning to general laws to observations within theories (Gustav Hempel)? Is science nothing more than extension of logic and philosophical discourse to what is real in the world (Willard Quine)? Does science actually just augment our common sense view of an objective world which doesn't actually exist (Wilfred Sellars)? The list goes on with each philosopher of science.
Everybody and their brother claims to know what science is, and sometimes bad actors intentionally try to commandeer the term science and apply it to non-scientific theories and practices. For instance, the intelligent design movement was a deliberate attempt to pass off fundamental Christianity as science. Another example is medical quacks who try to push homeopathy as a medical science. Ufologists are often lumped in with these pseudoscientific communities, whose members, like Stanton Friedman push back. Philosophers of science are those scholars who come best prepared to these discussions.
Ultimately, the philosophy of science is simply a community that seeks to build a body of scholastic research encompassing the history, the science, the linguistics, and the speculations and debates on what it means to be 'science'. Ironically, they often are dismissed by working scientists as irrelevant, uneducated, or wrong. One thing is certain is that philosophers of science have certainly influenced the trajectory of philosophy itself since modern professional philosophers of both the Continental and analytic traditions have strongly embraced the idea that the sciences should inform philosophical discourse itself, a view advocated by Quine in his naturalized epistemology (SEP).

All I do is read books about science and nature because that’s what I liked as a kid. I loved to learn about the world around me and understand how things work. That love shaped my interest in media and the characters I love in fiction, etc. I even want to get into IT because I like computers and technology. But when it comes to philosophy I just don’t get it. I understand what the terms mean but not what people mean by them or what they are saying when they argue something. Then I’ll find something that upsets me and cling to it for months if not years.

@BoltStorm Philosophy is very language-centric, and small gradations in syntax can mean large differences in meaning. Science is fun stuff, and you certainly don't have to read philosophy of science to understand and enjoy or even do science. Philosophy of science can be thought of as nothing more than a long-term project to define 'science', and in that sense it appeals to those who like to bicker over words. If you have a hard time latching onto the nuances of language, it is what it is.

"Then I’ll find something that upsets me and cling to it for months if not years". Talk to a therapist, not philosophy people.

@JonathanZ I thought the same thing, but then I remembered that philosophy, according to Wittegenstein, IS therapy. ; ) How many of our mental health issues are derivative of an inaccurate view of the world. Mine certainly are! :D

@JD I think therapy is a bit different from philosophy in my experience with it. Philosophy doesn't seem to have set answers to things but therapy is more trying to show me the world isn't as bad as it is. Though unfortunately for my therapist the evidence of my life doesn't support what they're telling me. That said stuff like the philosophy of science has me thinking we don't know anything if there is no set standard and now I find myself doubting all the books I love to read because of it. I'm thinking "is this right", "is it true or is it just defined that way and what that even mean"?

If you are somewhat familiar with mathematics, perhaps an analogy will help. Whenever we talk about mathematical 'truths', there's an explicit (or assumed) set of axioms. Why does 1 + 1 = 2? Because the axioms of arithmetic logically lead to that result. If we pick different axioms, the answer to 1 + 1 could be something wildly different.
So, what are the axioms of science? What does it mean for something to be scientific? What even is science? Can you define it? While it might seem obvious, the concept of 'science' as we understand it today was not how it was understood in the past. In ancient times, it was believed science could be deduced. One of my favorite examples of this is the ancient theory that sight was a product of beams that emanated from the eyes. Another useful example was Aristotle's belief that heavier objects fall faster.
I think I am not going too far out on a limb to say that Galileo was the person whose challenges to these ideas led to science as we know it today. He built upon the logical science of the past by adding verification. This came to be known as empiricism which is the foundation of modern science.
But coming full circle, why is empiricism a superior approach? The simple answer is that it works, but that is not a very satisfying answer. At a very fundamental level, empiricism is like an axiom. We cannot prove that empiricism is correct. It's a philosophy (one that I very much adhere to.) If you can show otherwise, you will be very famous.

Well the beams from the eyes isn't ENTIRELY off the mark, I can see why they'd think that with field of vision and all that. Sight is part of the brain but without eyes you ain't doing shit. Also I don't think "it works" is a bad answer, that's pretty much how humans live. The fact that it works and has led to everything we have so far is proof enough that it's correct in my book, if it wasn't I doubt all this would exist. Just calling it a philosophy is underselling it in my view. Empiricism isn't an axiom, the axiom is the external world and other people and minds. Empiricism is the method.

@BoltStorm "Well the beams from the eyes isn't ENTIRELY off the mark, I can see why they'd think that with field of vision and all that." Well, it is actually completely off-the-mark. It's completely backwards. "Also I don't think "it works" is a bad answer" It isn't a bad answer at all. It's a pretty strong argument. But why?

"Nothing succeeds like success" So 'works' beats the heck out of the alternative.

@JimmyJames Well no, we take stuff in and process it, it's closeish, which is better than nothing (maybe). But I think we can prove empiricism is correct just by showing...that it works. I mean our society as it exists is the result of it. I'm not seeing any other alternative.

@BoltStorm That's all good and well but the point is that empiricism is a philosophy or at least part of a philosophy.

@JimmyJames Perhaps at the start but I tend to measure things by results. And the fact that something works (while not definitive that it’s true) seems pretty strong a case, again since society operates and functions on it. At least better than mysticism of the past.

@BoltStorm I agree. Not sure what that has to do with fact that it's still a philosophy. What is a measurement? That's non-trivial in itself.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/measurement-science/

@JimmyJames I think it is trivial. You observe and record something and that’s a measurement. Again, you keep saying these things aren’t trivial but given the success of empiricism I would say they are. I guess to me calling it a philosophy is kinda downplaying it’s success since most philosophy, IMO, doesn’t really have the track record science (or empiricism) does:

You are asking a very good question, but you will probably be surprised that good questions usually don't get answers.
From my side, I could say that I always loved to read about science and books on philosophy put me to sleep after several pages.
The main trick in life (for some of us) is how to trigger the process. Meaning, when your subconscious starts working on its own, asking, collecting, analyzing, connecting the dots. And sometimes giving you a new understanding, as out of the blue.
I guess this is what philosophy is for. To facilitate. To trigger the thought.

Philosophy has a habit of mucking my brain up, not triggering thoughts or facilitating the process. I end up stuck on the same point for months.

This is good! It is a sign of the process. The fruits come later.

That’s actually very bad, it’s not a sign of the process when you’re stuck on the same point for months and years. It means you don’t get it. Like I said, I’m autistic so letting things go isn’t really a thing for me. It either gets resolved or I agonize over it for years.
